# Ignore multi-factor authentication in azure graph API request

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, multi-factor-authentication

I want to validate user credential from Azure AD. It works for users who haven't enable MFA.but MFA enabled users getting below error.

> Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because
>   you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication
>   to access

**So it need a way to ignore MFA ,when we accessing though the graph API**

this is my code.

```
     var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
        { "grant_type", "password" },
        { "client_secret", appKey },
        { "client_id", clientId },
        { "username", userName },
        { "password", password },
        { "scope", "User.Read openid profile offline_access" },
        };

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string requestUrl = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token";
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

        var response = client.PostAsync(requestUrl, content).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Yes the grant type you are trying is not supported for MFA that's why user who enabled MFA are getting that error.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to validate user credentials is have the user authenticate interactively through a browser.
This will allow them to go through MFA, login through federation with ADFS etc.
And most importantly, the users do not have to give their password to your app.

The flow you are trying to use only exists in the spec as an upgrade path for legacy applications.
Its usage becomes essentially impossible once MFA is enabled.